# How do I find the smallest number in a list of floats without using any arrays?

Tags: java

I would like to find the smallest number in a list of floats from the file that the user types in without using any arrays, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. This is what I have currently but it doesn't work at all. Any help would be appreciated and please feel free to edit for phrasing.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Excercise3 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the file name: ");
    String filename = sc.next();
    File myFile = new File(filename);

    String myString;
    float incumbant = 0;
    float secondPlace = 0;
    float counter = 0;

    try {

      Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(myFile);
      myScanner.nextLine();

      //while(myScanner.hasNextFloat())
      //{
      counter = myScanner.nextFloat();
      if (counter == 47.83) {
        System.out.println("The top qualifier is: " + counter);
      } else {
        counter++;
      }
      //System.out.println(myString);

      //  }

      myScanner.close();
      sc.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: have you looked at the possible lists? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: What are `incumbant` and `secondPlace`? I think you're on the right track but need to figure out the loop. What's with `if (counter == 47.83)`, where does that number come from?

Comment: Why would you want to use an array?

Answer (score 1):

Just keep track of the lowest number.  If the next number is lower, then it's the new lowest.  You shouldn't need any storage except the one float variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
 float min;
if (myScanner.hasNextFloat()){
  min=myScanner.nextFloat();;
}
while(myScanner.hasNextFloat())
{
  counter = myScanner.nextFloat();

  if (counter<min) {min = counter};

  if (counter == 47.83) {
    System.out.println("The top qualifier is: " + counter);
  } else {
    counter++;
  }
  //System.out.println(myString);

}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there is a problem with the scope of `min`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your counter in `Float.MAX_VALUE` and replace it every time a number is smaller than the current counter.

```
float newNumber = myScanner.nextFloat();
if(newNumber < counter) {
    counter = newNumber;
}
```

At the end the smallest number will be -> counter.

Comment: `Float.MAX_VALUE` is okay if you actually have floats but if the file is empty it will look like a minimum was found anyway.

Comment: Then you may have to make a final validation using a flag to know if the file had at least one number.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to keep track of the lowest number while you scan the file (using a List or other data-structure as a commenter suggest may only hide the array - depending on the implementation). Your code should use the while loop you've commented out. If your min value starts at positive infinity you don't need a separate step for the first float. The heart your code would something like this (though I confess I'm making some assumptions about what `counter` is suppose to do and eliminating the mysterious 47.83):

```
float min = Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
float temp;
int counter = 0;

try {
   Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(myFile);
   myScanner.nextLine(); //Are you sure you want to skip the first line?

   while(myScanner.hasNextFloat()) {
      temp = myScanner.nextFloat(); //get next float
      if(temp<min) min=temp;        //keep smallest float so far
      counter++;                    //count floats checked
   }

   myScanner.close();
   sc.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("File not found.");
}
```

In the end, `counter` is the number of floats you've checked and `min` is the smallest float. If you had no floats, `min` would be positive infinity.